# How to append the query in sp?

Tags: sql

Suppose there are 3 textbox for *firstname*,*lastname*,*city*.
Based on entries in textboxes, it is added in where clause.
Here is my query.

```
select col1,col2 from table1 where
```

Suppose to put name into *texfirstname*, then the query will be like this

```
select col1,col2 from table1 where firstname = txtfirstname.Text
```

and if user enter lastname in *textlastname* then query will be like this

```
select col1,col2 from table1 where firstname = txtfirstname.Text and lastname = txtlastname.Text
```

I am appending in main query based on what the user enter in the textboxes.

How to do this in a stored procedure, if a user fills a textbox?

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Procedure spTest
(
  @Value nVarChar(10)
)
As
Begin
   Select col1,col2 from table1 where firstname = @Value 
End
```